# How to add value from one query to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm using React to send data to my PostgreSQL database using NodeJS. I have a foreign key in my songs table that REFERENCES to the id in my albums table. My question is how can I return (or whatever needs to be done) my id from my first INSERT to the album_id in my second INSERT? Here's my code currently:

```
const addData = (request, response) => {
const uuid = uuidv4(); 

db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *' , [request.body.title, request.body.date, request.body.description, uuid])
    .then(res => {
      console.log('INSERT ' + JSON.stringify(res.rows[0].id));
    }).then(() => {
       for (let i = 0; i < request.body.files.length; i++) {
        db.pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (id, name, link, index) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (album_id, index) DO NOTHING RETURNING *', [uuidv4(), request.body.files[i].name, request.body.files[i].link, request.body.files[i].index])
       }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log('INSERT INTO songs ' + JSON.stringify(res));
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));

}
```

I haven't added album_id yet to my songs INSERT. I'm waiting to see how I can get the value from id of albums into my second INSERT?

Comment: The `console.log` immediately after the query to insert into the albums table logs the album id, yeah?

Comment: Please provide your tables structure

Answer (score 1):

As I can not see the `album_id` column in songs table so I am not writing the query for that.

You just need to pass that last inserted id to the next using `then(album_id)`

```
const addData = (request, response) => {
const uuid = uuidv4(); 

db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *' , [request.body.title, request.body.date, request.body.description, uuid])
    .then(res => {
      let album_id = res.rows[0].id;
      console.log('INSERT ' + JSON.stringify(res.rows[0].id));
    }).then((album_id) => {
       console.log("album_id " + album_id); 
       // here you will get the album id and now you can use it as per required.
        .....
        .....
      //   
    }).then(res => {
      console.log('INSERT INTO songs ' + JSON.stringify(res));
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));

}
```

Comment: What I did was set `let album_id;` before all queries and then added `album_id = res.rows[0].id;` after the first query and then set the album_id in the second query. Your code helped me though. Let me know if I should make any tweaks in my code.

Comment: Regarding changes in your code, as per my answer, now you can get album_id so now its on you how you will use album_id for the second query. please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you.